# VSCode programmatically find latest extension version on marketplace

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In a custom view for my VSCode extension, I would like to display whether the extension is up to date or not, and what the latest version of the extension on the marketplace is.

**Does anyone know of a way to dynamically determine what the latest version of an extension on the VSCode marketplace is?**

For example, the marketplace page for this handy extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer&ssr=false#overview shows the version to be 1.0.61